# C# converting png image to list of points

Tags: c#, image

I have a .png image, i want to get the points that the shape is made of.
Example:
[image]

I know that i won't get a perfect output but anything would be good..

How should I start?

I would need to get a list of points out of my image.

Comment: You might want to look into vectorization.

Comment: @mbeckish some links would be great.

Comment: [Here are all the links](https://www.google.com/?q=vectorization)

Comment: The key to doing this is always to be __very__ precise as to what your situaton is: one or many such images? full or semi-automatic? which colors? which resolution? do we know anything about the shapes, the tilt angle etc etc.. From there one can decide on how to best solve the problem. Often one will search for an edge, then follow it and search for the corners. Maybe one will prepare the image by reducing colors or even reducing resolution. Of course the very first question is: make or buy or find a library that does it for you..

Comment: The shapes are very basic, i make a program that will create the outline of images for games. That i will use later with box2d something like box2d editor

Answer (score -3):

Very simple. Replace an NON white pixels by black. Then loop in each black pixel and turn them white if not adjacent to at least 1 white pixel.

Comment: This will result in an image containing black for the edges and white everywhere else, but the OP is looking for a list of points that make up those edges.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the OP wants the output to be the points where the edges meet - not a bunch of points that are along the edges.

Comment: I know and if you get the list of black pixel you get collection o x,Y points which is what he is asking. that shape is made of hundreds of points.

Comment: @Franck As the question indicates, the example shape is *not* made of hundreds of points -- it is made of only 10 points. The answer should give a list of these points, not just an edge-detection image.

Comment: @Jashaszun sorry to inform you that this image edge is not straight and is made of actually 73 poly lines and that's according to solidworks. So that said there are actually 72 vertex only for the edges and NOT 10 as you state.

Comment: Why don't you simply __look__ at the desired output: 10 fat dots <-> 10 points.